# Perform MVCPaging which is SEO friendly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I am trying to use MVC paging, I have created a partial view and place it in a View, to which I am passing IPagedList, now when I perform paging, I use following code 
`<%:Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "dv1" }).Options(o => o.Action("IndexPaging").AddRouteValue("currpage","page"))%>` and IndexPaging returns PartialView, but my problem is that, on paging, I do not get to see the 2nd page data in view source. My requirement is to make it SEO friendly, so that when google crawler crawl's through my paging, it can read other page's data.

Comment: What happens when you right click on that link and click "open in new tab"? The AJAX may have an ordinary link as a fallback.

Comment: When I do that, It throws  javascript error " jquery is undefined", but opens the partial view as a page, which should not proper.

Comment: When working on an SEO version of a site, i always disable javascript and then go through it looking for points where its content will be lost because it relies on javascript.  try that and see what happens

Comment: I disabled the java script, paging is still working but view source is always showing data of that of first page, no matter which ever page I be on. I want to perform partial post back along with view source available for all pages, can anyone help please???